# Building Deployment Azure With Database Migration Scripts

Tags: sql-server, iis, azure, deployment, data-migration

We are very new to Azure, we have a large existing website (multiple instances with different customers) with an associated windows service and SQL Server 2008 database.

We are in the process of migrating the website in development to Azure. We are creating an Azure worker role to wrap the code that the Windows service executes to run every hour but my main concern is deployment, in an ideal world we will automate the deployment but for now we want to get to the following point where we can build a single deployment package for a customer which runs the database migration scripts to the Azure SQL database and migrates the web role and site and during this time a holding page is displayed to let users know the site is currently being updated. Also it would be great if there was a way to rollback if something goes wrong.

Despite my research I cannot find the answer to the process above, everything seems to involve deploying the database changes (this will include custom scripts for data migration/changes) and then publishing the site to Azure from visual studio but as we want to deploy this multiple times it would be ideal to build a package that we run against each customer site/database when we/they are ready to migrate to the next version as this may not always happen at the same time.

Our current deployment strategy is a mess, we stop the application in IIS and then start another one which shows a holding page saying the site is being updated.  We then stop the windows service and manually copy the latest version overwriting the existing website and windows service.  We then run a SQL script which has any changes in on the database and then we restart the windows service and IIS application.

This is not sustainable but in my research I have not come across the best option moving forward.  I have looked at MSBuild but it is completely new to me and finding somewhere to start with such unfamiliar technology is proving hard.  I also looked at FluentMigrator and considered running our database changes from application_start but I am not sure I am comfortable with that.

As we are looking to move to Azure where we will have the site running with 5 different configurations at the moment we are looking at publishing profiles and the hosted build controller but I cannot figure out how to deploy the database with these changes.

I would appreciate some insight into how others handle deployments like this taking into account that we are using all the latest tech, VS2013, VSO, Azure, etc. and also that we need to be able to change the configurations for different customers and I am assuming publishing profiles is the best way to do that but I may be wrong.

Comment: 1st question - why are you trying to deploy your service in a web role?  In Azure, web services are typically deployed as worker roles, not web roles.

Comment: Sorry that's a typo, the website is in a web role and the service is in a worker role.

Comment: 2nd question - have you built the staging and production slots of the Cloud Service into your deployment strategy?  They are designed to handle just this kind of scenario.

Comment: We have begun looking at it but I must be missing something as it seems if we deploy to staging it will have it's own database that will be updated, this will then be swapped both db and roles with the production db and roles.  How does this leave any data changed on the live site while we were upgrading the staging or have I missed the point?  Should we take the production down while we are testing staging?  Is there a way to show an updating page on production?  Apologies for all the questions.

Comment: production/staging slots are just for web/worker roles - they have nothing to do with the DB.  Once new code is deployed to staging, you get a temporary URL to browse/test your code until you swap the VIP.  DB is a different story - if you deploy breaking changes you have to handle breaking changes.

Comment: I see what you mean, so I guess the staging will have it's own db connection and so will production so when we swap we'd have to ensure the db for production was migrated too.  If we have settings though in web.config will they get swapped too, I guess they would,  This is probably why all settings need to be in the azure panel and RoleEnvironment used to retrieve them.  I think it's making more sense, thanks for your comments.

Comment: The ConfigurationSettings section in ServiveConfiguration mirrors the appSettings section in the web.config file and when used in conjunction with CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("settingsKey") with look first in the ServiceConnfiguration then in the web.config for application settings, allowing you to run locally in an emulator or just IIS express and achieve the same functionality. So we duplicate the settings in both ServiceConfiguration and web.config.